# Installing IronPython+Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 64-bit: VS2010 can't find ipy Interpreter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython

This is a dumb question -- you guys will answer in seconds... I'm doing some work with IronPython on Windows .NET 4 and develop/debug in Visual Studio 2010.  I moved to a Macbook Pro with 64-bit addressing and reinstalled IronPython and the Python Tools for VS 2010.

Seems ok; ipy works fine.  But Visual Studio insists that no IronPython interpreter is installed.

So I go to Tools>Options>Python Options>Interpreter Options and tell it that C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe is the interpreter (this is a guess; also tried ....\ipy64.exe).

No luck: when I try to run sample programs, the ipy.exe launches in console mode and says it was passed '""' as an argument.

Has anyone seen this?  Why didn't the IronPython or the PythonTools for VS 2010 script set these variables up?  What values are they supposed to have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following settings work for me in VS2010 and python tools for visual studio (I tried 1.1 and 1.5) and IronPython 2.7.1 on Windows 7 64:

**Own configuration**

[image: Using own configuration in 1.1]

**Automatically provided values in 1.5**

[image: Automatically provided values in 1.5]

I checked with pre-existing and new Python and IronPython applications.